# HAVING clause doesn't work without using allias

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a having clause to check if an aggregated value is contained in a sub-query. When I use an alias everything works, however if I chose not to use one the having clause returns no matches. For the sake of testing I removed the sub-query and just used some numbers and using the aggregated value in the having clause was fine, but if I use the sub-query it doesn't work unless I use the alias.

The clause I have a problem is the second one (after the or). When i use count(challenge_id) it doesn't work. If I use some numbers instead of the sub-query (count(challenge_id) in (1,2,3,4,5)) it works fine, however if I use the sub-query I get no results unless I use the alias. Hope I'm clear enough...

```
select c.hacker_id, name, count(challenge_id) as chal_count from challenges as c
    join hackers as h
    on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
    group by c.hacker_id,name
    having
    chal_count = 
        (select max(chal_count) from 
            (select count(challenge_id) as chal_count from challenges as c
            join hackers as h
            on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
            group by c.hacker_id,name) as d)
    or
    chal_count in 
        (select chal_count from 
            (select count(challenge_id) as chal_count from challenges as c
            join hackers as h
            on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
            group by c.hacker_id,name) as d
            group by chal_count
            having count(chal_count) = 1)
    order by chal_count desc, c.hacker_id
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? can you provide the error message please?

Comment: There's no error message, It just doesn't return any results when it should be. As I said if I use the alias it is returning everything correctly, however if I use the aggregated function I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand SQL order of operation, you'll know why your code doesn't work.
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

`HAVING` is evaluated before `SELECT`, and you put the alias in`SELECT`, so you can't use the alias in `HAVING`.  Repalce `chal_count` with `COUNT(challenge_id)`.

Comment: Yes I know that, the problem is that the query is only working when I USE the alias. When i use the count(challenge_id) it doesn't return the correct results.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your count somewhere. I would strip it back and validate each sub-query first @Eric is stating that this is expected behaviour. which is correct

Comment: The count is fine and I checked all the queries. It is a simple matter of using the alias vs not using the alias and when I use the aggregated function I just don't get results. When I use the alias everything is fine.

Comment: @TonyoZhelev It doesn't make sense that you can reference `chal_count` in your `HAVING` clause.  Are you sure your query is the same as the posted query?